# PHP combine parse_str with trim or any other sanitize filter

Tags: php, trim, sanitization

I need to trim or sanitize the text while using `parse_str` function.

I try with this but the text is not actually trimmed:

```
parse_str(trim($_REQUEST['data']), $v);
```

For example, i get these results:
- passing `"   "` i get `" "` instead of `""`;
- passing `" a "` i get `" a "` instead of `"a"`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not actually trimmed"? Can you share an example?

Comment: Of course, if i pass a string composed by 3 white spaces, i get " " but i should instead get "". Same thing with "  a  ", i get " a " instead of "a".

Comment: @JayBlanchard Nope, the same happens with a string containing chars. and anyway if i `echo trim("   ")` i get "" as expected.

Comment: There must be something else going on then, something in the data that we're not seeing. I just tested this in a PHP fiddle and it worked fine.

Comment: What is in `$_REQUEST['data']`?

Comment: Testing with the data you gave in comments below shows [all to be working fine](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ie49-srv6)

Comment: It's the serialization of a form, so `var1=a&var2=aa&var3=aaa`. mopo922 provided a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
parse_str($_REQUEST['data'], $v);
$v = array_map('trim', $v);
```

If you want to trim whitespace from each element in the query string, first convert your query string to an array with `parse_str()`, then `trim()` each resulting element of that array.

**EDIT**

Based on one of your comments above, you may be looking for something more thorough than just `trim()`. If that's the case, you can define your own "sanitizing" function and use it with `array_map()` instead of "trim":

```
function sanitize($input)
{
    return trim(str_replace(' ', '', $input));
}

parse_str($_REQUEST['data'], $v);
$v = array_map('sanitize', $v);
```

Comment: With your code I get `Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`. `$_REQUEST['data']` is not an array.

Comment: @Mariano What does your `$_REQUEST['data']` look like?

Comment: @Mariano Fixed, plz try again.

Comment: @mopo922 i'm gonna try. `$_REQUEST['data']` is a form serialized by an ajax function, so it looks like this: `var1=a&var2=aa&var3=aaa`

Comment: @mopo922 thanks, with the code you updated (the first one) it does the trick! :)